# Generate multiple sequences of numbers with unique values at each index

Tags: algorithm, matlab, random, sequence, combinatorics

I have a row with numbers `1:n`.  I'm looking to add a second row also with the numbers `1:n` but these should be in a random order while satisfying the following:

1. No positions have the same number in both rows
2. No combination of numbers occurs twice

For example, in the following

```
Row 1:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ...
Row 2:  3  6  15 8  13 12 7 ...
```

the number 7 occurs at the same position in both rows 1 and 2 (namely position 7; thereby not satisfying rule 1)

while in the following

```
Row 1:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ...
Row 2:  3  7  15 8  13 12 2 ...
```

the combination of 2+7 appears twice (in positions 2 and 7; thereby not satisfying rule 2).

It would perhaps be possible – but unnecessarily time-consuming – to do this by hand (at least up until a reasonable number), but there must be quite an elegant solution for this in MATLAB.

Comment: Given say, 10 people, would you be happy if three of them were in a cycle separate from the rest? e.g. `1->2` `2->3`, `3->1`. If you would prefer to ban any such divisions in the group, then I've described a simple solution in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward. Create a random permutation of the nodes, but interpret the list as follows: Interpret it as a random walk around the nodes, and if node 'b' appears after node 'a', it means that node 'b' appears below node 'a' in the lists:

So if your initial random permutation is

```
3 2 5 1 4
```

Then the walk in this case is `3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 1 -> 4` and you creates the rows as follows:

```
Row 1:  1 2 3 4 5
Row 2:  4 5 2 3 1
```

This random walk will satisfy both conditions.

But do you wish to allow more than one cycle in your network? I know you don't want two people to have each other's hat. But what about 7 people, where *3* of them have each other's hats and the other *4* have each other's hats? Is this acceptable and/or desirable?

Comment: In hindsight: it took me a bit longer to understand what you meant but _theoretically_ this seems to be the most elegant solution, as it doesn't require any looping ("trial and error")!

Comment: @user1092247, No problem, I had to edit my answer a little to make it more readable. Feel free to suggest any rewording.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is called a *derangment* of a permutation.
Use the function **randperm**, in order to find a random permutation of your data.

```
x = [1  2  3  4  5  6  7];
y = randperm(x);
```

Then, you can check that the sequence is legal. If not, do it again and again..
You have  a [probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of about 0.3 each time to succeed, which means that you need roughly 10/3 times to try until you find it.
Therefore you will find the answer really quickly.

Alternatively, you can use [this algorithm](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/analco08.pdf) to create a random derangment.

**Edit**

If you want to have only cycles of size > 2, this is a generalization of the problem. 
In it is written that the probability 
 in [that case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers) is smaller, but big enough to find it in a fixed amount of steps. So the same approach is still valid.

Comment: I think it's a partial derangement.  To extend the analogy in the PDF document you linked to: while no gentleman should be getting back their own hat (derangement), there should also be no two gentleman that have _each other's_ hat (rule 2, see my edit).  Perhaps one can create in matlab a script that compares a randomly generated sequence of '1:n' for these two rules until it finds one that satisfies both?

Comment: @user1092247, I have updated my answer. Welcome to SO. If you liked my answer, don't forget to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey has already pointed you to `randperm` and the rejection-sampling-like approach. After generating a permutation `p`, an easy way to check whether it has fixed point is `any(p==1:n)`. An easy way to check whether it contains cycles of length 2 is `any(p(p)==1:n)`.

So this gets permutations `p` of `1:n` fulfilling your requirements:

```
p=[];
while (isempty(p))
    p=randperm(n);
    if any(p==1:n), p=[]; 
    elseif any(p(p)==1:n), p=[]; 
    end
end
```

Surrounding this with a `for` loop and for each counting the iterations of the `while` loop, it seems that one needs to generate on average `4.5` permutations for every "valid" one (and `6.2` if cycles of length three are not allowed, either). Very interesting.

Comment: This is a great piece of code! The solution satisfying the second condition (using "p(p)") works well (even though it indeed requires "trial and error"-looping). Thanks!